# What is wasted in this example from the Cpp Core Guidelines?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

What is wasted in the example from the Cpp Core Guidelines?

> **P.9: Don't waste time or space**
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> void lower(zstring s)
> {
>     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i) s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
> }
> ```
>
> Yes, this is an example from production code. We leave it to the reader to figure out what's wasted.

from https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rp-waste

Comment: What lib is `zstring` coming from?

Comment: The space between `for` and `(`.

Comment: @MaxZoom It's from the GSL, or Guideline Support Library. They're still working on completely specifying it, but Microsoft has a cross-platform [implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL), and [working definitions](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/144) for the [`span`](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0122r3.pdf) and [`byte`](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0298r1.pdf) portions of the library are going through standardization with the goal of being included in C++20.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Interesting, thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

strlen is calculated at every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 12):

`strlen` is called every time the loop condition is checked, and takes O(n) time per call, so the total time for the loop is O(n^2).

Answer (score 7):

A lot of time is wasted and a segmentation fault may occur as the author of the code's increasing `s`, not `i` in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++s)
                 //right here ^^^^
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't propagate the notion that a segmentation fault is guaranteed, since this is a C++ question, not a "every platform known to exist" question :)

Comment: It actually works, because `strlen(s)` will decrease for each round in the loop, and eventually reach `i`.

Comment: @melpomene, kinda makes `i` redundant as an index since its value never changes :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Sure, but that just makes it weird, not wrong.

Comment: @melpomene, well it's wasteful (a whole integer!!). So by the core guidelines it's bad.

Answer (score 5):

As other aswers have already stated, `strlen(s)` is called multiple times because it is in the condition, implying that it should be cached and reused instead.

But `strlen(s)` does not actually need to be called at all ! `s` is (or is implicitly convertible to) a nul-terminated `char` array, since that's what `strlen` expects. So we can just use this very property for our own loop.

```
void lower(zstring s) {
    for (char *p = s; *p; ++p)
        *p = std::tolower((unsigned char)*p);
}
```

Comment: @RolandIllig alright, so passing in a negative-valued char would expand into a negative `int`, that is neither representable by `unsigned char` nor an `EOF`. that makes sense, fixed it :)

Comment: Are you wasting space by declaring p? Can't you just use s?

Comment: @DavidThomas that's a bit overkill IMO. Leave that to the optimizer -- a quick test on [Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/dFO7lv) shows that the generated assembly is perfectly identical with and without `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless they have any very unintuitive semantics in the `zstring` class, the function in it's current form is a complete waste of both time **and** space, as its "result" can't be used after the function - it is passed in as value, and isn't returned.

So to avoid wasting the time to uselessly compute the lowercase which can't be used, and  the space in copying the passed parameter, I would pass by reference!